# Sort by category and then date on Wordpress homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress site has multiple custom categories and posts types all which need to be displayed on the home page blogroll. But I need the first post on the homepage always to be the most recent post from a specific category.

For example the pst at the top of the page will always be the latest "giraffe" category; and below it; sorted default/chronologically are more "walrus" mixed with "seagull" and "nachos"

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you just use sticky posts for your most recent posts in the "Giraffe" category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without running through the Loop twice, sticky posts are your best option.

Otherwise:

```
...
$args = array(
 'orderby' => 'post_date',
 'category'=> 'giraffe',
 'numberposts'=> 1,
);
$latest_giraffe_post = get_posts( $args );    
...
```

then do what you're already doing for the rest